# Algebraic set with just one element defined by polynomials in a subfield, are the coordinates in the subfield?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F\subset L$ be fields, where $L$ is algebraically closed. Let $x\in L^n$ be a point such that $\{x\}$ is the set of simulatenous solutions to a set $S$ of polynomials over $F$. I want to prove that $x \in F^n$.

I managed it the following way: If $x\notin F^n$ then $x_i\notin F$ for some $i$. The field $F(x_i)$ has an automorphism $\varphi$ fixing $F$ pointwise, but sending $x_i$ to some $y_i\neq x_i$ (to see this, I separated to two cases: $x_i$ algebraic over $F$, and $x_i$ transcendental over $F$). Applying $\varphi$ to each entry of $x$, we obtain a different common solution for $S$, a contradiction.

I'm wondering if there's an even more elementary way. Just playing with polynomials or something. Or at least not separating to the algebraic and transcental cases.

**Edit**: Following KReseier's comment, I should add another question: Does the proof above make sense to you?

Comment: What about $\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$, $n=1$, $x=i$, and $S=\{x^2+1\}$? This shows that your first claim (that $x_i\in F$ for some $i$) is not necessarily true.

Comment: @KReiser: Oops, that should have been  $x_i \notin F$. Edited. Does it make sense now?

Comment: No, it does not make sense. It is the first couple sentences, the statement of the result, that is wrong. You can just pick $S$ to consist of one polynomial with no root in $F$, then the statement is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @KReiser What you write is not a counter-example, since $\{ i\}$ is not the set of solutions, $\{i, -i\}$ is. The fact that the set of solutions is a singleton seems crucial here.

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes, I realized that after posting (though it did identify a small bug in the proof as written at that point). An inseparable extension will give a correct counterexample, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is wrong, but for different reasons than I said in the comment. Let $F=\Bbb F_p(t)$, let $L=\overline{F}$, take $n=1$, and take $x=(t^{1/p})$. Then $x$ is the unique solution of the polynomial $Z^p-t$ over $L$, since $Z^p-t=(Z-t^{1/p})^p$, but $x\notin F$. The reason the statement fails here is that the extension $F\subset L$ is not separable.

In the case when $F\subset L$ is separable, then $F\subset\overline{F}$ is Galois and you can work from here. If some coordinate of $x$ is not in $F$, then there is a field automorphism moving it, but such a field automorphism preserves $S$ and therefore $V(S)$ is not a singleton over $\overline{F}$, so it is not a singleton over $L$. (This is pretty much your proof.)

Comment: So the problem with my argument is that a minimal polynomial of an element $\alpha$ outside a field $F$ might still have only $\alpha$ as a root?

Comment: @Object yes, exactly - this only occurs in the case if an inseparable extension though.